# How to enable .htaccess on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, apache2, .htaccess

I installed apache+mysql+php on my ubuntu 13.10. I want to use customized .htaccess file. But it is disabled by default on ubuntu system. There are some tutorials on how to enable it on ubuntu 12.04 but there are no tutorial on how to enable it on ubuntu 13.10.

Could anyone show me how to enable .htaccess on ubntu 13.10 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE: you must do these command as root

You have to create the folder that you have to be authenticated. Since the default location in apache is /var/www/ then create your folder there. You will do this by using the mkdir command.

```
 mkdir /var/www/html/testfolder
```

Add the .htaccess & .htpasswd files to the personal folder.

```
 cd /var/www/testfolder
 gedit .htaccess
```

Add thos commands to the .htaccess

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/testfolder/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /www.null
AuthName "Authorization Required"
AuthType Basic
require user USER_NAME
```

Change "test folder" to the name of your folder and change "USER_NAME" to the user name you wish to use.

Now create the .htpasswd file. We want to run htpasswd on the path of the folder we want to protect.

```
 htpasswd -c /var/www/html/testfolder/.htpasswd USER_NAME
```

You should see something like this:

```
 New password:
 Re-type new password:
Adding password for user USER_NAME
```

you have to edit the apache httpd.conf (on some systems called the apache2.conf) file.

```
 gedit /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

add the following .

```
#FOR MY TEST FOLDER
 <Directory "/var/www/html/testfolder">
 AllowOverride AuthConfig
 </Directory>
```

Now restart apache

```
  service apache2 restart
```

Comment: This isn't working when using userdir (per user) access.  I followed the steps above with "<Directory /home/*/public_html>" in the httpd.conf.  However, the .htaccess remains disabled.